# Wordpress раскрыть меню сайдбара активной категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Я вывожу структуру таким образом:

```
<?php
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
$orderby      = 'name';  
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
$title        = '';  
$empty        = 0;

$args = array(
       'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
       'orderby'      => $orderby,
       'show_count'   => $show_count,
       'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
       'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
       'exclude'      => 15,
       'title_li'     => $title,
       'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
  if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
      $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
      echo '<li class="drop_aside_li submenu"><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

      $args2 = array(
              'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
              'child_of'     => 0,
              'parent'       => $category_id,
              'orderby'      => $orderby,
              'show_count'   => $show_count,
              'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
              'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
              'title_li'     => $title,
              'hide_empty'   => $empty
      );
      $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
      if($sub_cats) {
        echo '<span class="arrow"></span>';
        echo '<ul class="dropdown_aside">';
          foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
            //   var_dump($sub_category);
              echo '<li>';
                echo  '<a href="'. $sub_category->slug .'">' . $sub_category->name . '</a>' ;
              echo '</li>';

          }   
      echo '</ul>';

         
      }

      echo '</li>';

  }       
}

?>
```

Что даёт мне по итогу такой вид:

1. Категория 1

   Подкатегория 1

   Подкатегория 2
2. Категория 2
3. Категория 3
4. Категория 4

По умолчанию подменю скрыты и если нажимать на стрелочки, то они раскрываются. Всё просто. Но мне нужно, чтобы подкатегории сразу были раскрыты, если товар относится к Подкатегория 1 и т.д. Так выходит, что я раскрыл список, нажал на категорию, страница обновилась и список снова свёрнут.

Answer (score 1):

Это уже дело не wp и php, а css. Подменю имеет класс .dropdown_aside. Ищите ответ в стилях этого класса

Comment: Понял. Думал, что и вп так может. Да, так-то через js+css можно. Спасибо